# xmodmap in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to do the magic which `xmodmap` does with python?

Use Case: I want to add a new layer to the current keyboard layout which gets entered with the CapsLock key.

I want to avoid to call `xmodmap` via `subprocess`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to implement `xmodmap` in pure Python by using a Python X11 client implementation such as `python-xlib` and re-implementing the functionality of `xmodmap` itself (i.e. updating the X11 server keyboards mappings with all the appropriate X11 functions, e.g. `XSetModifierMapping` to name but one).

The `xmodmap` source code is available so 'all' you need to do is translate it into equivalent Python code.

However, the real question is why go to all that trouble when X11 provides a utility written to do just that (`xmodmap`)? There is little point in re-inventing the wheel when the easiest and most reliable approach to run `xmodmap`.

Comment: [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-xlib)'s a pure Python X11 client that you could use.

Comment: There's a reason why one would want to use Python bindings to X11 libs (e.g., python-xlib). I have a 20-line .xmodmap and calling xmodmap from within my Python script takes a very perceptible half-a-second - a glitch in the GUI that I would like to avoid.